# Yarn install has been replaced with `add`

Tags: yarnpkg

On my Windows system I can run `yarn install` with no issue in my project. But during my Azure build which is running on `Ubuntu-16.04` I get the following message:

> error: `install` has been replaced with `add` to add new dependencies. Run "yarn add yarn build" instead.

Doing a `yarn add` gives this message:

> error: Running this command will add the dependency to the workspace root rather than the workspace itself, which might not be what you want - if you really meant it, make it explicit by running this command again with the -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check).

In my project I have multiple applications all with their own `package.json` file. If I'm reading the message correctly the `yarn add` will add all the dependencies to the root file and not in the directories where the `package.json` files are located.

So how do install the packages per directory/package.json file using yarn add?

Answer (score 2):

Initially I added: `yarn add --cwd apps/<foldername>/<foldername>` to the build script. You can do this for multiple folders to initiate different builds. But just running `yarn` from the root also resolved all the different builds.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into something very similar. In my case I was missing `--` for the immutable flag, so yarn was thinking I was trying to install the `immutable` library.

So in my build I was doing `yarn install immutable` when it should have been `yarn install --immutable`.

It looks like OP had a similar issue where yarn thought he was trying to run `yarn install yarn build` (iow `yarn add yarn` and `yarn add build`).

If you're here from Google, check your commands and make sure line breaks and hyphens are all in the right places.